# Нажатие на ссылку вызывает нажатие на другие ссылки с таким же data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, битрикс

Коллеги, прошу помочь, сломал всю голову.

На сайте есть блок с торговыми предложениями, при клике на цвет меняется картинка, это делает битрикс стандартными свойствами. Тут все гуд!

```html
<div class="elementSkuProperty" data-name="TSVET" data-level="1" data-highload="Y">
<div class="elementSkuPropertyName">Цвет:</div>
<ul class="elementSkuPropertyList">
  <li class="elementSkuPropertyValue selected" data-name="TSVET" data-value="98b599f3-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297">
  <a href="#" class="elementSkuPropertyLink">Венге</a>
  </li>
  <li class="elementSkuPropertyValue" data-name="TSVET" data-value="98b599f5-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297">
  <a href="#" class="elementSkuPropertyLink">Дуб</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Но ниже есть еще один блок, он схож по смыслу, он выводит связанные товары

```html
<div class="skuProperty" data-name="TSVET" data-level="1" data-highload="Y">
<div class="skuPropertyName">Цвет</div>
  <ul class="skuPropertyList">
    <li id="#skuPropertyValue" class="skuPropertyValue selected" data-name="TSVET" data-value="98b599f3-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297">
    <a href="#" class="skuPropertyLink">Венге Магия</a>
    </li>
    <li id="#skuPropertyValue" class="skuPropertyValue" data-name="TSVET" data-value="98b599f5-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297">
    <a href="#" class="skuPropertyLink">Дуб каньон</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вопрос в чем, как можно средствами Jqery, реализовать что при нажатии пользователем в верхнем блоке на цвет (венге или дуб), скрипт нажимает на кнопку в нижнем блоке с таким же цветом?

Тут у тега li есть уникальный атрибут

```html
data-value="98b599f5-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297"
```

Такая реализация нужна т.к. на этих кнопках уже висят обработчики. Добавление класса selected не помогает, т.к. нужно именно нажатие, т.е. запуск другого скрипта.

Другими словами: клик на li class="elementSkuPropertyValue" с data-value="98b599f3-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297" скрипт делает клик на li id="#skuPropertyValue" с data-value="98b599f3-9461-11e7-8fae-e61f13e71297"

Answer (score 0):

В jquery есть метод trigger, его и пробуйте использовать.
Что-то типо такого:

```
$(function() {
    $('.elementSkuPropertyValue ').on('click', function() {
         var value = $(this).data('value');
         $('#skuPropertyValue[data-value=\''+ value + '\']').trigger('click')
    })
 })
```

Comment: спасибо! а ее нужно как то подцелять к к клику? т.е. на ссылке делать onClick(function)? Добавил в текст, заменил дата-валюе но ничего не происходит

Comment: Нет, ее не нужно подцеплять, она срабатывает при клике.Я не могу сказать почему она у вас не работает, смотрите в консоль, напишете alert() в функции, посмотрите срабатывает ли она вообще. Посмотрите на какой действительно элемент нужно нажать через консоль браузера к примеру так:
`jQuery($0).trigger('click')`
где $0 - это текущий элемент

Comment: а вы можете посмотреть на сайте? я готов отплатить. http://guryanova-bitrix-6.tw1.ru/catalog/kabinety_dlya_rukovoditeley/furniture_series/kabinet_torrs.html?clear_cache=Y 
для вас просто а для кого то сложно)

Comment: Тогда вам лучше обратится на фриланс биржу.

Comment: да, я бы рад сам, но не выходит
прописал alert() в $(function() {}  и в on('click', function() {}. но сообщения нет, оно должно быть в консоле? или на экране? 
Я правильно понимаю в вашем коде идет сначала обращение к классу, а потом к ID элемента?

Comment: У вас id прописан с '#' и клин должен срабатывать на ссылке внутри li а не на самом li, смотрите в этом направлении. Я бы поменял шаблон компонента, добавив в него нормальные классы по которым можно обращаться.

Comment: добавил id  ссылкам  
получаем верхняя ссылка   
<a href="#" id="elementSkuPropertyLink" class="elementSkuPropertyLink"></a>   
должна кликать по нижней  
<a href="#" id="skuPropertyLink" class="skuPropertyLink"></a>  
вот этим кодом  
$(function() {                 $('#elementSkuPropertyLink ').on('click', function() {                      var value = $(this).data('value');                      $('#skuPropertyLink[data-value="<?=$arNextPropValue["VALUE"]?>"]').trigger('click')                 }) })

Answer (score 0):

после клика на сыслку, в javascript ловите этот event, и в callback функции пропишите `return false`, либо `preventDefault();`

Comment: А вы можете примером написать?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы обьяснить распространение события в JavaScript нужно потратить не мало времени, вам стоит почитать документацию, либо же посмотреть какой-либо урок. Я также попробую вам помочь.

У меня есть 3 блока, и на каждом из них есть событие onclick. Первый блок является дочерним блоком второго, второй - третьего. То есть, вложенность блоков:

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="block-inside">
        <div id="block-last"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

в JavaScript напишем:

```
document.getElementById("block").onclick = function () {
alert("block");
};

document.getElementById("block-inside").onclick = function () {
alert("block-inside");
};

document.getElementById("block-last").onclick = function () {
alert("block-last");
};
```

Теперь, при нажатии на block-last, у меня почему то будет показывать 3 алёрта? Почему?
Это и называется распространением. При нажати block-last идёт заглубление к данному блоку. Чтобы вам было легче, просто представим что парсер при клике оказывается сразу на этом блоке, и отыгрывает его callback функцию на ивенте onclick, но чтобы работать с элементом DOM дальше, парсеру как-то нужно выйти с данного блока, по этому он и выходит с него но при выходе затрагивает родительские элементы, на которых также есть onclick, который он отыгрывает. Если на тэг body или html вы повесите событие onclick, т при нажатии на блок, это событие также отыграется.